# How do I not return {ModuleName = Admin} from the linq query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get the string value "Admin" from a linq query, but when I do:

```
string oldModule = dc.Modules
                             .Where(x => x.Id == um.ModuleId)
                             .Select(s => new {s.ModuleName})
                             .FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

It returns { ModuleName = Admin } in the oldModule variable instead of just Admin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you've introduced an anonymous type into the projection. Try this:

```
string oldModule = dc.Modules
                     .Where(x => x.Id == um.ModuleId)
                     .Select(s => s.ModuleName)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

I removed the `ToString` call as well, which would have thrown a `NullReferenceException` if the `Where` clause hadn't matched anything.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot I could do it with just s => s.ModuleName, for some reason, I have it stuck in my head that when I need to select individual columns and not everything, I have to do s => new {...}

Answer (score 2):

```
       string oldModule = dc.Modules
                         .Where(x => x.Id == um.ModuleId)
                         .Select(s => s.ModuleName)
                         .FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

What about just selecting the `ModuleName` property?

```
(from m in dc.Modules
 where m.Id == um.ModuleId
 select m.ModuleName).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because new {...}  creates a new anonymous type in Select. When you call ToString(), you call it on this anonoymous type, not the ModuleName string. If you just write .Select(s=>s.ModuleName) you will get back a string instead of the anonymous type and oldModule will contain Admin.

In fact, you don't even need ToString() at the end of the query, as the result of FirstOrDefault() is already a string.

Comment: After I removed the new and just did s => s.ModuleName, resharper told me ToString() was redundant, lol.  Can you explain an anonymous type?  Thanks for the short explanation by the way.

Comment: Let me jump ahead, is it because when I do s=> new {s.ModuleName}, it does not know what s.ModuleName's type is or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: An anonymous type is a type that gets generated by the compiler when it encounters the new{ ...} syntax. It has no specific name, which is why it is called anonymous. The compiler generates the type by creating one property for each item it finds inside the curly braces. In your case the compiler created an anonymous type with a property called ModuleName whose value is Admin.  You can find a lot more about them at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: So would a better name be Anonymous Name as opposed to Anonymous Type?

Answer (score 0):

What is the new doing in

```
.Select(s => new {s.ModuleName})
```

I don't know what you're issue is, but I wouldn't be surprised if that's part of it..

I would also maybe just do .Single(s => s.ModuleName) instead of .select and .firstordefault.

Comment: i'm not 100% familiar with linq 2 sql.  I really don't understand the difference between Single, SingleOrDefault, First, FirstOrDefault